# Email from my Google Apps domain to a specific server is being regularly truncated

Tags: email, email-server, g-suite, exchange

My organization is using Google Apps for non-profits and we're seeing a strange but regular behavior between two specific domains. We're regularly seeing that emails sent from our domain (cureinternational.org, hosted on Google Apps) sent to Penn State University (psu.edu - possibly on Exchange) is regularly generating seemingly half-delivered content. A message will begin with a greeting or perhaps a sentence or two and then the rest of the message will be empty. I have wondered if perhaps there is an encoding or attachment issue in the email content causing the error, but I haven't been able to pinpoint anything. Looking for diagnostic advise if not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it may come down to networking interoperability. If possible, the ideal first approach is to observe the actual SMTP transaction as it enters into the problematic system/infrastructure to see if the entire SMTP transaction completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you guys are directly related in regards to this situation, it looks like there may be some issues with your Google Apps hosted service...

https://serverfault.com/questions/163150/email-receiving-glitch